# Safari CSS height transition issue

Tags: css, safari, transition

I found out my menu bar does not work properly on Safari. 
I when I hover my "work" list-item a bar should appear under the menu bar. 
It works perfectly in other browsers such as Firefox and Chrome.

Here is the link to my project: http://i305098.iris.fhict.nl/Portfolio/

Thanks!

Comment: please post your relevant markup here, not on an external lnk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the change you make on hover:

```
header nav li:hover {
    height: 120px;
    line-height: 120px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Simply remove height and line-height and it’ll work. I don’t understand why you did those changes actually.

```
header nav li:hover {
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```